# Работа с памятью при использовании Git

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Постараюсь быть максимально кратким.
На [сайте русской документации по Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git) дается такое объяснение принципу его работы:

> Git считает хранимые данные набором слепков небольшой файловой
>   системы. Каждый раз, когда вы фиксируете текущую версию проекта, Git,
>   по сути, сохраняет слепок того, как выглядят все файлы проекта на
>   текущий момент. Ради эффективности, если файл не менялся, Git не
>   сохраняет файл снова, а делает ссылку на ранее сохранённый файл.

[image: Визуальное представление принципа работы Git]

Так вот, если очень грубо допустить, что размер текстового файла стремится к 1Мб, то следуя логике работы Git при даже самом малом изменении в этом файле(исправили ошибку в слове), будет создаваться "слепок"(=копия) файла, размером ~1Мб.

**Вопрос: насколько это выгодно с точки зрения используемой памяти, или же текстовой файл как-то делится на более мелкие файлы, и созданию "слепков" подлежат уже они?**

Comment: Данная документация не раскрывает "подробностей" формата, думаю... на каждую копию не тратится 1Мб, даже если файл занимает 1Мб. Файл бьется скорре всего на куски. Делаются ссылки на куски.

Comment: Надо найти более подробное описание механизмов гит - и тогда можно делать выводы. При даной постановке вопроса - гит - "черный ящик". Формулировки приведены так, что б не разжёвывать и не раскрывать детали работы, а так, что б был понятен общий принцип (и пользователи гита не волновались что их файл исщезнет).

Comment: А точно файлы целиком хранятся? Не дифы ли? Когда изменения не большие выгоднее хранить разницу - смещение и данные

Comment: Если данный вопрос Вас интересует с практической точки зрения, — то есть, как сжать файлы в папке `.git` и ничего не поломать, — воспользуйтесь командами из [**данного ответа**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116892/5951529) (бэкап на всякий случай предварительно сделав). В моём проекте, например, я сэкономил порядка 200 МБ: [**было**](https://i.imgur.com/aMvcfY1.png) — [**стало**](https://i.imgur.com/52cQ1AL.png). Спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Кратко: приведенная схема - это объяснение наблюдаемого поведения GIT. Если вы будете работать с GIT стандартными командами и не будете лезть руками в бинарные файлы - всё будет выглядеть как будто все так и работает. Но это вовсе не означает что на каждую версию файла будет и правда тратиться по мегабайту...

Потому что на более низком уровне, гит все-таки использует дельты между файлами. Прочитать про них можно вот тут: [Git изнутри - Pack-файлы](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-Pack-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B)

Однако, упаковка файлов происходит не всегда, а только при достижении некоторого порога числа распакованных объектов или при пушу коммитов в удаленный репозиторий. При наличии больших файлов в некоторых случаях приходится явно выполнять команду `git gc` для переупаковки всех блобов (нам, к примеру, однажды пришлось добавлять эту команду в билд-скрипт, потому что на билд-сервере отправка в удаленные репозитории никогда не происходит и локальный репозиторий бесконтрольно рос).

Comment: «локальный репозиторий бесконтрольно рос» — а вы убирали трекающие ветки с помощью `git fetch --prune`? Я б в первую очередь на них списал увеличение объема.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ветки сами по себе 10 гигов не выжрут никак :-)

Answer (score 7):

Как раз об этом повествует ["Git изнутри - Pack-файлы"](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-Pack-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B). Собственно, там и ответ на вопрос:

> Однако, время от времени Git упаковывает несколько таких объектов в один pack-файл (pack в пер. с англ. — упаковывать, уплотнять) для сохранения места на диске и повышения эффективности. Это происходит, когда "рыхлых" объектов становится слишком много, а также при вызове `git gc` вручную, и при отправке изменений на удалённый сервер.

То есть, через какое-то время в процессе эксплуатации репозитория различающиеся версии файла попадут в один Pack-файл, который представляет разные версии гораздо более эффективным образом: через основу и дельты (разности, изменения).

Answer (score 4):

> или же текстовой файл как-то делится на более мелкие файлы, и созданию "слепков" подлежат уже они?

Нет, файлы (как и любой другой объект, например, папка — список пар «имя дочернего объекта — его хэш») сохраняются именно целиком. Это, кстати, повышает «выживаемость» репозитория — если часть объектов по каким-то причинам будет повреждена или стёрта, остаётся крайне высокая вероятность восстановления если и не последнего commit-а, то хотя бы одного из последних.

Однако параллельно с объектным хранилищем (`./git/objects`) есть и сжатое, где все объекты хранятся в одном упакованном файле (`.git/objects/pack/`) в виде diff-ов. Туда можно поместить любой объект, при этом оригинальный файл объекта удаляется.

Так как операция упаковки является достаточно трудоёмкой, она выполняется только при вызове команды `git gc --force`. При этом любые дальнейшие изменения в репозитории (добавление commit-ов и переписывание истории) продолжат добавление объектов в основное хранилище; во втором же случае в pack-файле также останутся «хвосты», которые будут удалены только при следующем вызове `git gc`.

Answer (score 3):

> TL;DR Файлы в гит хранятся целиком и не делятся. Это достаточно
>   выгодно.

Есть хорошие статьи по git ([пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/313890/), [пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/143079/)), где раскрывается внутреннее устройство гит.

> Пользователь запускает git add на data/letter.txt. Происходят две
>   вещи.
>
> Во-первых, создаётся новый блоб-файл в директории .git/objects/. Он
>   содержит сжатое содержимое data/letter.txt. Его имя – сгенерированный
>   хэш на основе содержимого. К примеру, Git делает хэш от а и получает
>   2e65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e. Первые два символа хэша
>   используются для имени директории в базе объектов: .git/objects/2e/.
>   Остаток хэша – это имя блоб-файла, содержащего внутренности
>   добавленного файла:
>   .git/objects/2e/65efe2a145dda7ee51d1741299f848e5bf752e.
>
> Заметьте, что простое добавление файла в Git приводит к сохранению его
>   содержимого в директории objects. Оно будет храниться там, если
>   пользователь удалит data/letter.txt из рабочей копии.

Далее показывается механика того, что происходит когда файл меняется.

> Когда пользователь создал data/number.txt, он хотел написать 1, а не
>   1234. Он вносит изменение и снова добавляет файл к индексу. Эта команда создаёт новый блоб с новым содержимым.

Можете посмотреть файлы в папке object и через команду git cat-file -p увидеть разжатое представление ваших файлов.

Это механика на уровне отдельных файлов. Казалось бы - неоптимальный расход. Тем не менее, есть дополнительный механизм - когда происходит упаковка объектов в более крупные файлы.

Проблема с хранением больших файлов также привела к появлению [LFS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/255413/). Дело в том, что большие файлы, которые вы даже ни разу не правили (бинарники типа картинок) сохранять в git реально достаточно тяжело, поэтому их сохраняют на отдельные файловые хранилища.