# Git и бинарные файлы

Tags: git, git-commit, контроль-версий, binary

Если в Git репозитории есть бинарный файл, можно ли утверждать, что с каждым коммитом он сохраняет полную текущую версию этого файла и размер репо увеличивается на текущий размер этого файла?
Или он сохраняет дельту, как и для текстовых файлов?

Comment: Был недавно похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797025/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-git#comment1258183_797025 только может надо и правда память на диск поменять.

Comment: Полную версию сохраняет — да, размер репо увеличивается, но не на весь размер, там есть сжатие. И для текстовых файлов всё точно так же. Дельту гит не хранит, просто показывает дифф двух полноценных сохраненных версий.